# How do I extract the start_date and end_date columns as ranges for each user?

Tags: mysql

target_user

```
| user_id | start_date   | end_date   |
|   1     |  2020-01-01  | 2020-01-10 |
|   2     |  2020-01-02  | 2020-01-14 |
|   3     |  2020-01-01  | 2020-01-16 |
```

amount_table

```
| user_id | amount | date       |
|    1    |  100   | 2020-01-01 |
|    2    |   50   | 2020-01-15 | 
|    1    |   50   | 2020-01-02 | 
|    3    |  100   | 2020-01-04 | 
|    3    |   50   | 2020-01-14 | 
|    1    |   50   | 2020-01-11 |
```

my idea

```sql
select
    target_user.user_id,
    sum(amount) as amount
from
    target_user
join
    amount_table
on
    target_user.user_id = amount_table.user_id
where
    amount_table.date between target_user.start_date and target_user.end_date
group by 1
```

result

○...summed ×...not summed

```
| user_id | amount | date       |
|    1    |  100   | 2020-01-01 | ○
|    2    |   50   | 2020-01-15 | ○
|    1    |   50   | 2020-01-02 | ○
|    3    |  100   | 2020-01-04 | ○
|    3    |   50   | 2020-01-14 | ○
|    1    |   50   | 2020-01-11 | ○
```

Perhaps this extracts the period from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-16 for all users?

ideal

```
| user_id | amount | date       |
|    1    |  100   | 2020-01-01 | ○
|    2    |   50   | 2020-01-15 | ×
|    1    |   50   | 2020-01-02 | ○
|    3    |  100   | 2020-01-04 | ○
|    3    |   50   | 2020-01-14 | ○
|    1    |   50   | 2020-01-11 | ×
```

How do I extract the start_date and end_date columns as ranges for each user?

Answer (score 1):

> ideal
>
> ```
> | user_id | amount | date       |
> |    1    |  100   | 2020-01-01 | ○
> |    2    |   50   | 2020-01-15 | ×
> |    1    |   50   | 2020-01-02 | ○
> |    3    |  100   | 2020-01-04 | ○
> |    3    |   50   | 2020-01-14 | ○
> |    1    |   50   | 2020-01-11 | ×
> ```

---

> ```
> SELECT a.user_id, a.amount, a.`date`, CASE WHEN t.user_id IS NULL
>                                            THEN '×'
>                                            ELSE '○'
>                                            END ` `
> FROM ( SELECT user_id, amount, `date`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
>        FROM amount_table ) a
> LEFT JOIN target_user t ON a.user_id = t.user_id
>                        AND a.`date` BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
> ORDER BY a.rn
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | amount | date       |    
> ------: | -----: | :--------- | :--
>       1 |    100 | 2020-01-01 | ○
>       2 |     50 | 2020-01-15 | × 
>       1 |     50 | 2020-01-02 | ○
>       3 |    100 | 2020-01-04 | ○
>       3 |     50 | 2020-01-14 | ○
>       1 |     50 | 2020-01-11 | ×
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37fa68d73caf8f37673c3ca42b89c1c5)*